# TYPO3 8.7.8 Custom content element with custom fields in backend

Tags: typo3, typoscript, typo3-8.x

I've been searching for quite a while but couldn't find what I was looking for.

I've created two custom content-elements: parallax_content and bg_image.

In the backend for the time being I have the fields of a standard textmedia-element the code for which is as follows (from tt_content):

```
array('showitem' => ' 
  --palette--;
  LLL:EXT:frontend/Resources/Private/Language/locallang_ttc.xlf:palette.general;
  general,
  --palette--;
  LLL:EXT:frontend/Resources/Private/Language/locallang_ttc.xlf:palette.header;
  header,
  rowDescription,
  bodytext;
  LLL:EXT:frontend/Resources/Private/Language/locallang_ttc.xlf:bodytext_formlabel,
  --div--;
  LLL:EXT:frontend/Resources/Private/Language/locallang_ttc.xlf:tabs.media,
  assets,
  --palette--;
  LLL:EXT:frontend/Resources/Private/Language/locallang_ttc.xlf:palette.imagelinks;
  imagelinks,
  --div--;
  LLL:EXT:frontend/Resources/Private/Language/locallang_ttc.xlf:tabs.appearance,
  layout;
  LLL:EXT:frontend/Resources/Private/Language/locallang_ttc.xlf:layout_formlabel,
  --palette--;
  LLL:EXT:fluid_styled_content/Resources/Private/Language/Database.xlf:tt_content.palette.mediaAdjustments;mediaAdjustments,
  --palette--;
  LLL:EXT:fluid_styled_content/Resources/Private/Language/Database.xlf:tt_content.palette.gallerySettings;
  gallerySettings,
  --palette--;
  LLL:EXT:frontend/Resources/Private/Language/locallang_ttc.xlf:palette.appearanceLinks;appearanceLinks,
  --div--;
  LLL:EXT:frontend/Resources/Private/Language/locallang_ttc.xlf:tabs.access,
  hidden;
  LLL:EXT:frontend/Resources/Private/Language/locallang_ttc.xlf:field.default.hidden,
  --palette--;
  LLL:EXT:frontend/Resources/Private/Language/locallang_ttc.xlf:palette.access;
  access,
  --div--;
  LLL:EXT:frontend/Resources/Private/Language/locallang_ttc.xlf:tabs.extended,
  --div--;
  LLL:EXT:lang/locallang_tca.xlf:sys_category.tabs.category,
  categories',

  'columnsOverrides' => array(
    'bodytext' => array(
      'defaultExtras' => 'richtext:rte_transform[mode=ts_css]'
    )
  )
)
```

For my element parallax_content I would need the following fields:

- Header
- a checkbox "insert Logo"
- a bodytext
- an image selecting field

For image_bg I would need:

- an image selecting field
- a dropdown list with 2 items

But I'm struggling with understanding the code and how I would neet to adapt it so it would work. I've looked at the [documentation](https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/extensions/fluid_styled_content/7.6/AddingYourOwnContentElements/Index.html) but it doesn't really answer my question as it only shows one example of code with some lines but no explanation. I couldn't find the other documentation again where I gained just as "much" information as in the one linked above. I do understand some parts, for example the palette.header creates the whole header palette with header, header-link, alignment, date etc.

So my questions are:

Can someone explain to me how the code above works exaclty? Where does one element start and where does it end? what do "--palette--" and "--div--" do? how are the tabs created (e.g. general, media etc)? Is it possible to create my fields as listed above with these palettes? Can I create my own palette? If yes how? Or is there maybe a typoscript I can use/make to create my custom fields? Or would I need to create an extension for each of these elements? If possible I'd like to avoid this.

Yes, it's quite a lot of questions, I'm a novice in TYPO3 and not only trying to work with TYPO3 but also understand it as far as possible (at least for the things I need). My utmost priority is to understand the code above, but any pointers, explanations, help or even links to documentations (which I might not have seen so far) which could lead to a solution for my request I would greatly appreciate. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

in my current project I added a parallax effect to the textmedia element in the tt_content.

First I override the tt_content TCA:

```
'background_media' => array(
    'exclude' => 1,
    'l10n_mode' => 'mergeIfNotBlank',
    'label' => 'LLL:EXT:extension/Resources/Private/Language/locallang.xml:background_media',
    'config' => \TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\ExtensionManagementUtility::getFileFieldTCAConfig(
        'background_media',
        array(
            'minitems' => 0,
            'maxitems' => 1,
            'appearance' => array(
                'createNewRelationLinkTitle' => 'LLL:EXT:extension/Resources/Private/Language/locallang.xml:add_media',
                'showAllLocalizationLink' => 1,
            ),
            'foreign_match_fields' => array(
                'fieldname' => 'background_media',
                'tablenames' => 'tt_content',
                'table_local' => 'sys_file',
            ),
            // custom configuration for displaying fields in the overlay/reference table
            // to use the newsPalette and imageoverlayPalette instead of the basicoverlayPalette
            'foreign_types' => array(
                \TYPO3\CMS\Core\Resource\File::FILETYPE_IMAGE => array(
                    'showitem' => '
                            --palette--;LLL:EXT:lang/locallang_tca.xlf:sys_file_reference.imageoverlayPalette,
                            --palette--;;imageoverlayPalette,
                            --palette--;;filePalette'
                ),

            )
        ),
        $GLOBALS['TYPO3_CONF_VARS']['GFX']['imagefile_ext']
    )
),
'effects' => [
    'exclude' => true,
    'label' => 'LLL:EXT:extension/Resources/Private/Language/locallang.xml:effects',
    'config' => [
        'type' => 'select',
        'itemsProcFunc' => 'VENDOR\Extension\UserFunction\ProviderField->createEffectItems',
        'renderType' => 'selectCheckBox',
        'multiple' => true,
        'minitems' => 0,
        'maxitems' => 999,
        'items' => []
    ]
],...


\TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\ExtensionManagementUtility::addTCAcolumns('tt_content', $additionalColumns);
\TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\ExtensionManagementUtility::addToAllTCAtypes('tt_content', 'background_media,effects', 'textmedia', 'after:layout');
\TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\ExtensionManagementUtility::addToAllTCAtypes('tt_content', 'image_classes,text_classes', 'textmedia', 'after:layout');
```

Now I have 2 additional fields:
 - Background Image (FAL)
 - Selct Box (UserFunc) for own styles

My UserFunc (VENDOR\Extension\UserFunction\ProviderField->createEffectItems)

```
 /**
     * @param ConfigurationService $configurationService
     * @return void
     */
    public function injectConfigurationService(ConfigurationService $configurationService) {
        $this->configurationService = $configurationService;
    }

public function createEffectItems($config) {
        $settings = $this->configurationService->getSettingsForExtensionName('extension');

        $classNames = json_decode($settings['container']['effects'],true);
        if (!is_array($classNames)) return $config;

        $optionList = array();
        foreach ($classNames as $key => $val) {
            $optionList[] = [$val, $key];
        }
        $config['items'] = array_merge($config['items'], $optionList);
        return $config;
    }
```

Now I can define my own CSS classes in Typoscript setting...

Last but not least the FluidStyleContent Part:
I overrride the Fluid_tyled_content template Textmedia.html and Layout Detaulf.html.

```
<v:content.resources.fal uid="{data.uid}" table="tt_content" field="background_media" as="ceBackground">
        <f:if condition="{ceBackground}">
            {v:uri.image(treatIdAsReference: 1, src: ceBackground.0.id, maxW: 1920) -> v:variable.set(name: 'parallaxBg')}
        </f:if>
    </v:content.resources.fal>
<div id="c{data.uid}" {f:if(condition: '{parallaxBg}', then: 'style="background-image: url(\'{parallaxBg}\');" ')}">

</div>

For a multiple classes use: {data.effects -> v:format.replace(substring: ',', replacement: ' ')}
```

Best regards

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have to look this through but I could maybe use this for my own content elements. I'll see what I can do